# Partial differential equation problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In the partial differential equation $$(x+y)z_x-(x-y)z_y=0$$
change the variables $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$, $u=ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}), v=tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Can someone please help with this, don't where to start. Explanations for each step would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

More verbosely, what they mean is the following.

Consider a (smooth enough) solution $z=z(x,y)$ of the partial differential equation (PDE). $z$ satisfies, for all $x,y$ in the relevant domain, $$(x+y)z_x(x,y)-(x-y)z_y(x,y)=0\tag{**}.$$
Now, let $w=w(u,v)$ be such that
$$z(x,y)=w(\ln((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}),\,\tan^{-1}(y/x))\tag{*}.$$
What PDE does $w$ satisfy?

**Hint**: compute the partial derivatives of $z$ in (*) and plug them into (**).

Comment: I calculated a few partial derivatives but I'm not sure how they help.

Comment: $z_y=z_vv_y+z_uy_y$

Comment: You want an expressions for $z_x$ and $z_y$ that only involve $w_u$ and $w_v$. As I said, compute partial derivatives of $z$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ using equation (*). Ultimately, you want a PDE for $w$ that does not involve $z$.

Comment: $z_y=z_v(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+z_u(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}

Comment: I'm still a little lost, I just don't get how I go from z to w.

Comment: If $z$ is a function that is once-differentiable in its arguments, so too is $w$, given how I defined it above. The objective is to find a PDE for $w$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I solved it, my final answer was $w_u-w_v=0$, could you verify this for me please?